# How to reattach viking fire sprinkler head covers?

Tags: fire-sprinkler

I pulled one of these off during a project, but am struggling to figure out how I can reattach it.  There are 3 clips and the cover.

The sprinkler heads appear to be Viking VK457.

[image: front of cover]
[image: back of cover]
[image: sprinkler]
[image: sprinkler]

Comment: I believe the cover shown in the photos is damaged and the parts that connect it to the ring in the ceiling are missing.

Comment: To fix it see if you can get replacement parts, if not get a pro.

Comment: That might be why I think I can see the remains of white tape which was holding it on previously

Comment: How about a pic of the sprinkler itself, up in the ceiling? All in all, though, this may well be damaged beyond reinstallability. They are designed to come off _easily_ in case of a fire, and I doubt there is more than the most fleeting of thought given to reinstalling the covers - that's not their purpose in life.

Comment: @FreeMan edited the question with a picture of the sprinkler

Comment: Absolutely do not touch the sprinkler and it’s cover plates what do ever, it is illegal. Only qualified personnel/ sprinkler fitters can.

Comment: Is this always true though? (especially for 13D systems, which don't fall under NFPA 25's ambit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cover appears to be a two-piece design. The yellow brass-colored "top hat" shaped part that's still on the ceiling is supposed to remain attached to the white-painted disk. The two parts should not have separated when you pulled the cover off. Wiggle that top hat/collar part down off the sprinkler body -- I think it's just a friction fit, but turning it in a counter-clockwise direction wouldn't hurt just in case the part is threaded.

I'm not completely certain whether the collar and the painted disk are supposed to be *permanently* attached or whether they're intended to separate in case of fire/sprinkler activation. Out of an abundance of caution I'd assume the latter and buy a new cover. They surely must be available online. If you live in a metro region of any size there must also be fire suppression or fire sprinkler contractors in your area. I'd expect that if you telephone one and and sound knowledgeable and confident when you say "hey, I need a white painted cover for a VK457 head" they'll be happy to sell you a new part.

Comment: Yes, I've found [VKMGSMWH](https://www.qrfs.com/viking-mirage-white-fire-sprinkler-cover-plate), but that part looks much different than my original cover

Comment: Yup, you are correct, it was a two-piece design.  I was able to successfully pull the brass colored "top hat" down, no twisting necessary. Replacements were actually the large diameter design, [VKMGWH](https://www.qrfs.com/viking-mirage-large-diameter-white-fire-sprinkler-cover-plate)